# Haskell syntax for a case expression in a do block

Tags: haskell, syntax, monads

I can't quite figure out this syntax problem with a `case` expression in a `do` block.

What is the correct syntax?

If you could correct my example and explain it that would be the best.

```
module Main where 

main = do   
     putStrLn "This is a test"
     s <- foo
     putStrLn s  

foo = do
    args <- getArgs 
    return case args of
                [] -> "No Args"
                [s]-> "Some Args"
```

A little update. My source file was a mix of spaces and tabs and it was causing all kinds of problems.
Just a tip for any one else starting in Haskell. If you are having problems check for tabs and spaces in your source code.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

return is an (overloaded) function, and it's not expecting its first argument to be a keyword.  You can either parenthesize:

```
module Main where 
import System(getArgs)

main = do   
     putStrLn "This is a test"
     s <- foo
     putStrLn s  

foo = do
    args <- getArgs 
    return (case args of
                [] -> "No Args"
                [s]-> "Some Args")
```

or use the handy application operator ($):

```
foo = do
    args <- getArgs 
    return $ case args of
                [] -> "No Args"
                [s]-> "Some Args"
```

Stylewise, I'd break it out into another function:

```
foo = do
    args <- getArgs 
    return (has_args args)

has_args [] = "No Args"
has_args _  = "Some Args"
```

but you still need to parenthesize or use ($), because return takes one argument, and function application is the highest precedence.

Answer (score 14):

Equivalently:

```
foo = do
  args <- getArgs 
  case args of
        [] -> return "No Args"
        [s]-> return "Some Args"
```

It's probably preferable to do as wnoise suggests, but this might help someone understand a bit better.

Comment: This method does nicely emphasize the first-class nature of IO actions.